# Printing the HTML from an external Webpage

Tags: jquery, pdf-generation

I am Printing an HTML from an external webpage . Am I doing something wrong?

```
$('#createPDF').on('click',function(){
    newWin= window.open("");
    newWin.load("http://example.com", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        newWin.document.write(responseTxt);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem you experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
$('#createPDF').on('click',function() {
  var $trigger = $(this);

  $.get('http://example.com', function(data) {
      var newWindow = window.open("","_blank");
      $(newWindow.document.body).html(data);
      newWindow.print();
  });
  
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="createPDF">
  PDF print
</button>
```

**Or here an working example on** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/rb8t8gs4/)